# Upgrade 'dig' on Mac OS

Tags: mac, dns, bind, macos-sierra, dig

It seems I have accidentally broke the `dig` command on my Mac. Now I have version 0.1.10, how can I safely update this?

I can't seem to find any documentation on updating the internally loaded dig version.

```
$ dig --version

0.1.10
```

Comment: Edit your Question to also show the output of "which dig". It's possible you installed a new `dig` in a different directory than the system `dig`, so all you have to do is remove the new `dig` or edit your `$PATH` directory order.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed!

```
$ which dig
/usr/local/bin/dig
```